# Regenerating Wordpress shortcodes based on <select> value with AJAX

Tags: shortcode, ajax, javascript

I'm trying to generate & replace Wordpress shortcodes with AJAX based on the user's chosen `<select>` option.

I've posted my progress to date below - whilst the shortcodes *are* currently being replaced on form `POST`, it's not with AJAX - the full page is reloading. I've tried to keep the question as general as possible to (hopefully) help others too, but I've very little experience with AJAX, so any advice as to where I've messed up would be massively appreciated.

**PHP**

For context in terms of implementation; `[table_generator]` is the parent shortcode which houses both the form and generated 'child' shortcodes. When the user selects a provider from the dropdown and hits the submit button, a shortcode is generated below which displays a table of data relative to that provider. If the user then changes the provider in the `<select>` input and submits again, a new appropriate table is generated.

```php
function table_generator() {

    // Set product providers
    $providers = array(
        'Provider 1',
        'Provider 2',
        'Provider 3',
    );

    // Build provider selection form
    $output .= '<form id="submitProvider" action="" method="POST">';
    $output .= '<select name="provider_list">';
    $output .= '<option value="default" selected disabled hidden>Select a provider...</option>';

    // Loop through '$providers' array, creating <select> options
    foreach ($providers as $provider) {
        $output .= '<option value="' . $provider . '">' . $provider . '</option>';
    }

    $output .= '</select>';
    $output .= '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
    $output .= '</form>';

    // Generate shortcode based on selected provider
    if (isset($_POST['provider_list'])) {
        $selected_provider = $_POST['provider_list'];
        $output .= '<div class="table-container">';
        $output .= do_shortcode( '[child-shortcode table="'. $selected_provider . '"]' );
        $output .= '</div>';
    }   

    // Initially, only display 'submitProvider' form
    return $output;

    // AJAX: Generate/update table
    add_action('wp_ajax_updateTable', 'updateTable');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateTable', 'updateTable');

    // Return output on POST with updated 'child-shortcode'
    function updateTable() {
        return $output;   
        die();
    }

}

add_shortcode( 'table_generator', 'table_generator' );
```

**JS**

```js
$('#submitProvider').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'updateTable', 
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error");            
        },
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log("Success");
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the shortcode value by leveraging ajax, you need to modify the PHP code and jQuery as mentioned below:

```
function table_generator() {
    // Set product providers
    $providers = array(
        'Provider 1',
        'Provider 2',
        'Provider 3',
    );
    // Build provider selection form
    $output .= '<form id="submitProvider" action="" method="POST">';
    $output .= '<select name="provider_list">';
    $output .= '<option value="default" selected disabled hidden>Select a provider...</option>';
    // Loop through '$providers' array, creating <select> options
    foreach ($providers as $provider) {
        $output .= '<option value="' . $provider . '">' . $provider . '</option>';
    }
    $output .= '</select>';
    $output .= '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
    $output .= '</form>';
    return $output;
}
// AJAX: Generate/update table
add_action('wp_ajax_updateTable', 'updateTable');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateTable', 'updateTable');
// Return output on POST with updated 'child-shortcode'
function updateTable() {
    if (isset($_POST['provider_list'])) {
        $selected_provider = sanitize_text_field($_POST['provider_list']);
        $output .= '<div class="table-container">';
        $output .= do_shortcode( '[child-shortcode table="'. $selected_provider . '"]' );
        $output .= '</div>';
        wp_send_json(array('status' => 'success', 'html' => $output));
    }
    wp_send_json(array('status' => 'fail'));
}
add_shortcode( 'table_generator', 'table_generator' );
```

and change your javascript code as following:

```
$('#submitProvider').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action': 'updateTable',
            'provider_list': $("[name='provider_list']").val()
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error");            
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'success'){
                console.log(data.html);
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Based on the ajax response you can show the **html** output.

Comment: Hey Faham - thanks for your response. Unfortunately, the shortcode switch doesn't work at all now, and the page is still performing a hard reload. I appreciate it's a very open question, but is there anything else I may have missed? I've seen a couple posts from users with issues using `ajaxurl`, but that's a total stab in the dark.

Comment: Got it - I had to localize `ajaxurl`. Thanks for your help Faham! Will update with a final solution shortly.

Comment: @GraemeBryson I was under the assumption that you had already localized the script since you were using `ajaxurl`. Sorry my bad mate!!